What is the translation of inline in French?
Example:

Could you please provide inline responses to all the questions below?

By "inline", it means "in the body of the text" (i.e. inserting the answer just after the question, possibly using a different colour/font to highlight response). (Thanks None for writing this explanation).
What is the translation of inline in French? Google translate and Linguee suggest "en ligne" but I never heard that in French for that meaning, so I doubt this is correct.

If by "inline" you mean "in the body of the text" (i.e. inserting the answer just after the question, possibly using a different colour/font to highlight response)  then it is dans le corps du texte. To say the least your example sentence is not explicit, it lacks context.

@None thanks that's what I meant.

I'm not sure if this is related to what you're asking, but I was wondering about HTML specifically, and MDN says en ligne (éléments en ligne vs éléments de bloc).

Used when inserting text in an electronic document (such as an email) "inline" means "in the body of the text" and "in the body of the text" translates word for word in French: dans le corps du  texte (document, courriel, etc.)

Quand on veut répondre point par point à toute une liste de questions, il est parfois intéressant de répondre dans le corps du mail lui même plutôt que d'ajouter sa réponse au début ou à la fin du thread. Pour que ça reste compréhensible, il faut que le texte que l'on ajoute soit facilement identifiable. Typiquement, dans une couleur, ou une autre fonte... (Forum Ubuntu)


To say "inline" in French you can just say "à la ligne" but it basically means (as you already know) instead of adding words on the current line, why don't you go to the next line and start adding words there instead.

That would only work for a single line. You can't use it the way you use 'inline' in English where multiple lines can be inserted in an existing text.
